# Web services giving latest sea level pressure using GPS location

Tags: web-services, gps, pressure

Are there any web services providing latest sea level pressure using latitude and longitude from GPS?I know GPS provides the same, but we can acquire more accurate value from web services.

Thanks

Dheeps

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search returned many results for "weather API."

http://www.worldweatheronline.com/marine-weather-api.aspx this one seems to have what you're looking for. Though I assume that any weather API you will find will show surface pressure instead of "sea level." There isn't much atmosphere at sea level in Boulder, CO :) If you really wanted sea level pressure anywhere in the would you would have to use Standard Atmosphere equations to determine what the pressure would be given surface pressure.  If you wanted further accuracy you'd have to determine what precisely you mean by "sea level." The actual current height of the surface of the sea? Some constant 0ft/m altitude (which varies depending on if you consider the earth a perfect sphere or one of many geoid models).  This problem can be very easy or very difficult depending on what you actually need.